# How to substitute some values of one dataframe with other data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, substitution

I have two large dataframe, with the same column and row, but I need to substitute the `NA` of the first, based on the second. For example assume  data frame "DF1" is

```
DF1 <- data.frame(a=c(1,NA,3), b=c(4,NA,6))
```

and "DF2" is

```
D2 <- data.frame(a=c(NA,2,NA), b=c(3,5,6))
```

When there is `NA` in the "DF1", I want to substitute "DF1" with "DF2", and create a new "DF3", i.e

```
a   b
1   4
2   5
3   6
```

Could you help me with this please?

Comment: try `DF1[is.na(DF1)] <- D2[is.na(DF1)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
DF3 <- DF1
replace.bool.matrix <- is.na(DF1)
DF3[replace.bool.matrix] <- DF2[replace.bool.matrix]
```

Explanation:

We create `DF3`, which is a copy of `DF1`. Then we make a logical matrix `replace.bool.matrix` which we use to select the values in `DF3` to replace, as well as the values in `DF2` to replace them with.

This makes use of [select operations on data frames](http://www.r-bloggers.com/select-operations-on-r-data-frames/), for which there are many tutorials.

Comment: the trick works like a charm, and thanks for explanation too!

Answer (score 0):

This is much easier with the match() function:

```
 df1 <- data.frame(steps=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),date=c('2012-10-01','2012-10-01','2012-10-01','2012-10-01','2012-10-01','2012-10-01','2012-10-02','2012-10-02'), interval=c(0,5,10,15,20,25,0,5))

df2 <- data.frame(Interval=c(0,5,10,15,20,25),x=c(1.716,0.339,0.132,0.151,0.075,2.094))
if (is.na(df1$steps)==TRUE) df1$steps <- df2$x[match(df1$interval,df2$Interval)]
```